# Increasing,decreasing and total JavaScript

Tags: javascript, class, constructor, properties

I have a beginner predeterminate exercise in React js, but I don´t know how to do it without a "state" when I try set the counter.

Can anyone help me?

```js
class Counter {
  constructor() {
    //initialization of the counter variable
    this.counter = 0;
  }
  increaseOne() {
    //increase the value in one
  }
  decreaseOne() {
    //decrease the value in one
  }
  getValue() {
    //return the value
  }
}

let myNewCounter = new Counter();
myNewCounter.increaseOne();
console.log(myNewCounter.getValue());
myNewCounter.increaseOne();
myNewCounter.increaseOne();
console.log(myNewCounter.getValue());
myNewCounter.decreaseOne();
myNewCounter.decreaseOne();
console.log(myNewCounter.getValue());
```

My exercise have to show the following:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In vanilla JS you don't have any states built-in. You just change the value of a property.

With the `++` and `--` operators you can add or subtract with a value of 1. So in the `increaseOne` and `decreaseOne` methods change the value of the `this.counter` property.

```js
class Counter {

  constructor() {
    this.counter = 0;
  }
  
  increaseOne() {
    this.counter++;
  }
  
  decreaseOne() {
    this.counter--;
  }
  
  get value() {
    return this.counter;
  }

}

let myNewCounter = new Counter();
myNewCounter.increaseOne();
console.log(myNewCounter.value);
myNewCounter.increaseOne();
myNewCounter.increaseOne();
console.log(myNewCounter.value);
myNewCounter.decreaseOne();
myNewCounter.decreaseOne();
console.log(myNewCounter.value);
```

For the `getValue()` method you can also use a *getter* method, which acts like a property but actually returns the result of a function. But this is just a suggestion and should make little difference.

Comment: Thanks @emiel-zuurbier , How can I do if I would like increase or decrease more than 1 unit?

Comment: Not to be lame, but is that another question for your exercise? Because I can show you, but you'll learn it way better by figuring out for yourself. If it has nothing to do with the exercise, then let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your help @emiel-zuurbier , I have just found out the response